# Can one replace a tubeless tire with a tube?

Tags: repair

I have a tubeless tire on a mountain bicycle which is old and wasn't taken care of, and I want to replace it with something more maintainable, as (according to the YouTube videos I've seen) tubeless tires are harder to change.

Would I buy a tube and new tire and replace the old tire with it, or are the rims different?

Comment: Is it a real tubeless tyre?  Or is it a ghetto-tubeless where someone's just glued a tyre to the rim?  an "old bike" which was "not taken care of" might be less likely to have pricy tubeless, or your definition of "old" may not match ours.  Photos might help too especially one of the rim showing the profile inside the tyre well.

Answer (score 3):

All tubeless compatible rims can run tubes - that is how you deal with a puncture in on the track.

As far as tires, you can go with any tire that is the correct size for the rim. If you get a tubeless-ready tire, its possible to run a tube and then go back to tubeless using a sealant like slime or Stan's, and they are much lighter than a tubed tire.

Comment: If it is a true UST rim however, a non UST tire will fit, but could have air retention problems and potentially burp off the rim on a hard hit.